# Problem on page numbering using \input

Tags: page-numbering, input

My problem is the incorrect page numeration I get each time I use the `\input` command.

I tried searching around but I haven't managed to found a solution.
The class I use is `toptesi`, that is based on `book` class if I'm not mistaken.
Since I like to be able to edit a single chapter, each one of the chapter files has got its own preamble (that is the same for each chapter and for the main file), that is skipped in the main file using the `standalone` package.
Here is my code:

```
     \documentclass[12pt, cucitura]{toptesi}

      \usepackage{standalone}

      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

      \usepackage{afterpage}

      \usepackage{microtype}
      \usepackage{lmodern}

      \usepackage{amsmath}

      \graphicspath{{../Frontespizio/}, {../Introduzione/images/}, 
      {../capitolo2/images/}}

      \usepackage{textcomp}

     \usepackage{caption}
     \usepackage{subcaption}

     \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
     \addbibresource{../references}

 \begin{document}

\input{../Frontespizio/frontespizio.tex}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\setcounter{page}{0}

\input{../Sommario/sommario.tex}

\clearpage

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\listoffigures

\clearpage

\thispagestyle{empty}
\afterpage{\null\newpage}

\input{../Introduzione/introduzione.tex}

\clearpage

\input{../capitolo2/capitolo2.tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! What's the purpose of `\afterpage{\null\newpage}`?

Comment: @egreg It's the "best" way I've found to add a blank page. Feel free to suggest a better way to do that, if you know any.

Comment: What about `\cleardoublepage`?

Comment: I tried that, but doesn't work, so I resorted to that solution.

Comment: Add the `twoside` option to the class.

Comment: Also tried that, still not working. Anyway, I am not using `twoside` because I have to print the document only on one side.

Comment: So what are the blank pages for?

Comment: It's a Bachelor of Science thesis, my institute use this layout for it.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that `toptesi` and `standalone` conflict with each other.

Comment: I see... What will be the best way to fix the problem then?

Comment: Leave out `standalone`.

Comment: Thanks, will try that tomorrow. However I'll have to modify each files, deleting both the preamble and begin/end{document}, am I right?

Comment: If you leave out `standalone` then unless you do the equivalent of what it does, yes, you can only have one preamble and one `document` environment, so all `\input` and `\include`d files would need to be changed.

Comment: Note that nobody but you can compile your example right now, so if anybody did have an idea, they wouldn't be able to try it out without creating an example to play with first. Though if @egreg says it can't be done, the chances of this are remote.